# Counting the selected/checked boxes [EXCEL]

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

One of the columns (MONTHS), let's say column A in my ***raw*** data contains numbers ranging from 0-12. Now, in another sheet, I'd like to be able to count the number of observations with the selected / checked months as shown below:

[image]

How can I do that? I tried doing it with countifs but hit a snag because column A is numeric and when a user checks a box in the other sheet, it only evaluates to "TRUE". Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT:

The column of MONTHS LOOKS LIKE THE FOLLOWING:

[image]

Comment: That should not be a problem. You can easily match the value "TRUE" at any place like matching any other types of variables. We can help more if you provide a snapshot of *"the other sheet"* and an example result. And dont forget to post what you tried with `countifs`.

Comment: To count checked check boxes use `=COUNTIF(A1:A13,TRUE)`, change range as needed.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A:A,TRUE)` What's the problem?

Comment: @A.S.H the column in "*the other sheet*" is a numeric column.. not T/F.

Comment: @RikSportel,@Mrig column A is numeric.

Comment: Hello, it's just the definition of the data. cuz a blank cell / null value represents something else (EXPIRED). So, 0 month means it's not EXPIRED yet.

Answer (score 1):

This formula should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$13)*COUNTIF(F:F,$B$1:$B$13))
```

Adjust it to your actual data layout by adding sheet names to the ranges.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: - My bad, had a wrong reference when testing this one - Edited previous comment. I know your answers are usually the right ones - seen you around in the excel-vba tag.

Comment: @RikSportel no problem. See you around :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUMPRODUCT` will work for sure.

A solution is using an array formula as follows:
Let Sheet1, that has TRUE or FALSE in one column (let's say `Sheet1!A1:A12`. Then, there's some values from 1 to 12 in `Sheet1!B1:B12`)
Now you want to count the amount of numbers in say `Sheet2!F:F` that have the Sheet1 column A set to true.

The formula to do that would be:
`=SUM(COUNTIF(Sheet2!F:F,IF(Sheet1!A1:A12,Sheet1!B1:B12)))`

Remember to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER since it's an array formula.